# How to get know Load_status for SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a load_log table .In that table have one column as Load_status .I need to insert here "Success" or Failure".when from source table merge into destination table that time i need to insert Load_status=y if it failure Load_status=N where i will get this information while running the SSIS package.can any one have idea about these one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with T-SQL only.

**Sample:**

```
begin try
    Insert into TargetTable
    select * from SourceTable
    IF (@@ERROR = 0)
    BEGIN
        Insert into logtable values ('tablename', 'Y', getdate())
    END
end try

begin catch
    Insert into logtable values ('tablename', 'N', getdate())
end catch
```

You will be required to create a Linked server if it involves multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this information from the OnError event handler in the SSIS package.